# Где найти описание классов yii2 на русском?

Tags: php, yii2

Где найти описание классов yii2 на русском?

На сайте yiiframework.com есть api 2.0. Если конкретно, то вот тут: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/

Существует ли аналог на русском?

Comment: На сайте yiiframework.com есть api 2.0. Существует ли аналог на русском?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru

Comment: @E_p api a не гайд

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Думаю такого не сушествует, так как генерирует phpDocumentor (https://www.phpdoc.org/). К сожалению переводчика для phpDocumentor не нашёл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю такого не существует.

`API` документация, обычно генерируется автоматически из коментариев в коде.

Один из инструментов для этого `phpDocumentor` http://www.phpdoc.org.

Так как, весь код закоментирован на английском, то генерированный результат на английском.

Гайд переводят, так как он не меняется часто, a `API` нет. Его надо будет переводить/перепроверять после каждого коммита, что нереально.

**PS:** Гайд - http://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru